# Robin-Stocks wont install on my Linux mint system

Tags: python, linux, pip, linux-mint

once you type "pip install robin-stocks" 
it then shows

```
root@mint:/media/mint/668B-3D00/Nucamp_nad_Instabot/RobinhoodBot-master# pip install robin-stocks
Collecting robin-stocks
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robin-stocks (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for robin-stocks
```

Why is this showing when it clearly [is available on pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/robin-stocks/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`robin-stocks` is for Python 3 only. Your `pip` command is for Python 2. Do `pip3 install robin-stocks` instead.